# REST URL with Azure function via APIM

Tags: rest, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have a User function app which has 2 functions:

- CreateUser. POST + Route = "users"
- GetUsers. GET + Route = "users"

I want to expose these functions via API Management. Let's say the domain of API management is https://my-apim.azure-api.net

How can I expose those functions with the following URLs:

- CreateUser = POST https://my-apim.azure-api.net/v1/users
- GetUsers = GET https://my-apim.azure-api.net/v1/users

APIM requires API URL Suffix to determine the right API. So the URLs generated are (with userfunction as API URL Suffix):

- CreateUser = POST https://my-apim.azure-api.net/userfunction/v1/users
- GetUsers = GET https://my-apim.azure-api.net/userfunction/v1/users

I can leave the API URL Suffix empty to achieve the expected URLs, but that will be an issue when I need to add more APIs to the APIM in the future

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following steps:

1. Add URL Suffix in APIM: api/users
2. In APIM, select the API
3. Go to Design > Frontend section and remove the URL path there so it only contains /
4. Add a rewrite-uri policy to the API to append /users when forwarding the request to the backend service

The resulting URL will be https://apim-domain/api/users